# Download the zip file using DotNetZip in c# MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, download

The scenario:

1. filter a jquery datatable according to our need.
2. use download button present besides page length dropdown(its a simple button not a submit button). to download the images for the filtered data.
3. get the record ids from the table, make its array and send it to the controller.
4. In controller, fetch the file paths from the database associated with the record ids sent from the
   ajax req.
5. get the files, make a zip and send it back (in response) to the view (download).

as I mentioned the scenario I want the zip to get downloaded on the machine.
But the file is not getting downloaded.

**--------------------------Edit [solution]:---------------------------**

**After Trying Many Solutions I finally got the solution.**

So first, I used Controller Code as :

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Ajax_DownloadImages(int[] records)
        {
             #region Variable Declaration
             
             List<tbl_image_Details> obj_records = new List<tbl_image_Details>();
             tbl_image_Details singleRecord = new tbl_image_Details();
             var memorystream = new MemoryStream();
             int temp = 0;
            
             #endregion
            
             using (Symphony_webServer_DBEntities db = new Symphony_webServer_DBEntities())
             {
            
                 #region Get File paths from the database.
                         for (int i = 0; i < records.Count(); i++)
                         {
                              temp = records[i];
                              singleRecord = db.tbl_image_Details.Where(x => x.record_id == temp).FirstOrDefault<tbl_image_Details>();
                              obj_records.Add(singleRecord);
                         }
                 #endregion
            
                  #region Zipping and sending the data to download.
                          using (ZipFile obj_Zip = new ZipFile())
                          {
                                obj_Zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
                                obj_Zip.AddDirectoryByName("Images");
                                foreach (var file in obj_records)
                                {
                                    obj_Zip.AddFile(file.image_path, "Images");
                                }
            
                                Response.ClearContent();
                                Response.ClearHeaders();
                                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Myzip.zip");
            
                                obj_Zip.Save(memorystream);
                          }
                            memorystream.Position = 0;
                            return new FileStreamResult(memorystream, "application/octet-stream");
            
                  #endregion
            
    }
}
```

**The View:**
Create a simple button and call the download function on its click event as follows.
Function That requests the zipped data from server is-

**Note :** I used XMLHttpRequest object to make a request call because,
jquery ajax call is not efficient to handle the blob response content.

```
funtion DownloadImages(){
       // selecting the table
       var Displayedtable = $("#recordTable").DataTable();

       // fetching the rows of the table
       var datatable_rows = Displayedtable.rows().data().toArray();

       // creating an array to hold data.
       var table_data = new Array();
       
       // fetching data from each cell and putting it into the array.
       $.each(datatable_rows, function (index, value) {
                table_data.push(value['record_id']);
       });

       var records = JSON.stringify(table_data);
       var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
       ajax.open("Post", "/ReportsPage/Ajax_DownloadImages", true);
       ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       ajax.responseType = "blob";
       ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (this.readyState == 4) {
       
           var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
           console.log(this.response);
           alert(this.response);
           var fileName = "Myzip.zip";
           saveAs(blob, fileName);
        }
    };
        ajax.send(records);
}
```

This will definitely download the intended zip file.

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong? It's unclear specifically if you have any errors, or some specific unexpected behaviour? And what does `saveas()` do? That would appear to be important in the downloading process, yet you haven't shown it. But also...why not just use a regular hyperlink to download the files? Downloading via AJAX is a pain in the a**, as you've just discovered.

Comment: Or in fact, why use any server-side code at all for this? From your code I can see that all the data being placed into the Zip file originates on the client-side, so why not just use a client-side JavaScript ZIP library (e.g. JSZip is popular, I believe)? Then you wouldn't need AJAX or anything else.

Comment: When I used this solution I am getting no errors but file is not getting downloaded..I'm wondering whether the controller is getting the value or not.it is not stopping at the debugger breakpoint  in the controller

Comment: @ADyson because the images are on server..from those images I want to download few of them that's why it is server side

Comment: Oh ok I see, I didn't quite understand that bit. I thought you were just adding the rows from the table. So yes ok server-side is necessary. But the rest of my comments are now relevant, then. And what is `obj_records` in the C#? It doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: Obj_record is a list in which I am getting the file paths, I have not included that part in the question in which Iam fetching the paths from db

Comment: Ok. So then what is the purpose of sending the `records` variable in the request? That doesn't seem to be used in the method? Is it used in the part you've missed out. It really makes things unclear if you leave out code but then don't mention or explain it.

Comment: @ADyson where ? In the arguement ?

Comment: Yes I mean `records` in `Ajax_DownloadImage(int[] records)`...it's an input parameter, but it's never used in the method.

Comment: that is the record_ids which have been filtered by the user and requested to the server that, give me the images associated with these records. those ids are being used to fetch the image path

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  But again the missing code made it unclear. Anyway back to the downloading issue. We're also missing the code of the saveas() JavaScript function, as I mentioned at the start. That seems to be important. Can you show it please

Comment: there is no code for saveAs() because it is a javascript function which allows you to save the received content in the desired format

Comment: No, it's not standard javascript, it isn't built into every browser. If you didn't write it, it must have come from some library.

Comment: in that case it can be written in FileServer.js which I used along with DotNetZip nuget

Comment: I had solved the problem.

Comment: That's great. If you solved it please write an answer below for the benefit of everyone. If people like it you'll get upvotes to increase your reputation score

Comment: @ADyson I found the solution and edited the question. :) I also included those missing part of code which you wanted to see.

Comment: Ok but The answer should go in the **answers** section. It's not part of the question. That's how this site is supposed to work. It's a Q&A format. If you post the answer inside the question then it doesn't make sense (and people can't vote separately on the quality of the answer, and also it won't show up in search results, whereas questions with accepted answers rank much higher :-))